# How to Set custom positions for barcode scanner

Tags: ionic2, barcode-scanner

I am trying to create a barcode scanner with custom positions.

I can make a barcode scanner successfully with ionic 2, but if I click the button the scanner occupies the full screen.

I want to position the barcode scanner at the bottom of my mobile screen only. How can I realize this using the [barcode scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/) ?

Comment: did you find a solution? @Sakthivel

Comment: there is no way to set a barcode scanner with in a div .